# jQuery on() method inside click event executes regardless of click

Tags: jquery

I'm using two Bootstrap modals to view and edit events within FullCalendar.  When I click a calendar event, a small modal (modal 1) opens to show event details and an edit event button (and bind a click event to that button).  When I click the edit button, it hides the view modal and opens a larger edit modal (modal 2).

The problem is that the .on('hiden.bs.modal') event fires whenever the modal is hidden, and not only when the #edit-event-btn button is clicked.  Modal 2 always shows whenever modal 1 closes.  How can I make the on() method wait until the click event fires?  Would this be a job for a closure?

By the way, if I get rid of the on() method, then I end up with a page shifting problem caused by the Bootstrap modals.

```
// This is the click event function for the FullCalendar event.
function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $.get('myUrl1', {id: " . $network->id . ", eid: event.id}, function(data) {
        $('#view-event-modal').modal('show').find('#view-event-content').html(data);

        $('#edit-event-btn').click(function(e) {
            $('#view-event-modal').modal('hide');
            $('#view-event-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                $.get('myUrl2', {id:" . $network->id . ", eid:event.id}, function(data) {
                    $('#edit-event-modal').modal('show').find('#edit-event-content').html(data);
                });
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `.on('hidden.bs.modal'`  for this? Also not a good idea adding that listener inside another event handler

Comment: I mentioned above that without the .on method, I run into a different problem - a page shifting issue caused by toggling two Boostrap modals (they get confused).

Comment: Somehow I have to pass the event id in the 2nd get call.  The only way I know to do that right now is dynamically add the click event once the view event modal is loaded with the correct data (i.e. the 2nd ajax call depends on the first).

Comment: Fine but what I mean is just make the request and get rid of the modal event listener

Comment: Ok, but as I mentioned, the bootstrap modals then give me problems.

Comment: Basically, I need a way to ensure that the modals are being toggled independently.  The on() method appears to be achieving that.

Comment: But it is that event that is causing you the problems when you cancel out of the first one. Could replace it with a setTimeout()

Comment: Can you suggest a way to ensure that the first modal is completely hidden before showing the second modal?  What happens is the .modal-open class gets applied to both modals as if their both open at the same time.

Comment: I had tried a set timeout without luck.  I'll give it another go if that's the best alternative.

Comment: There is one alternative is setting a global variable flag and only making request in `if(buttonClicked)`

Comment: Can you explain how that might work?

Comment: need another modal hidden listener for `$('#edit-event-modal')` that sets `buttonClick = false` and when button is clicked set `buttonClick = true`

Comment: OK, I'll give that a go.  Thanks for your help!